# R -- paired dot plot and box plot on same graph: is there a template in ggplot2 or another package?

Tags: r, ggplot2, package, scatter-plot, boxplot

I am a new R user and found graphs I would like to replicate with my data.  From the look of the plot, it looks as though it was made in ggplot2.  I've searched and searched and can't find a template within ggplot2 or another package.  Just wondering if anyone has seen template code for this?

See attached image and paper here: http://ehp.niehs.nih.gov/1205963/

[image]

Comment: This is in the close queue as "offtopic" but I think it is okay despite the wording.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps this will get you started:

```
d <- data.frame(y = rnorm(20, 9, 2),
                group = as.factor(rep(c('Post-FAP', 'Post-DEP'), each = 10)),
                id = rep(1:10, 2))

ggplot(d, aes(y = y)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = rep(c(-3, 3), each = 10), group = group), fill = 'steelblue') +
  geom_point(aes(x = rep(c(-1, 1), each = 10)), size = 5) +
  geom_line(aes(x = rep(c(-1, 1), each = 10), group = id))
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks @Axeman.  You were right -- i needed somewhere to start.  Much appreciated.